# What's the relationship between the rank and eigenvalues of symmetric positive semidefinite matrix (real domain)?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Could anyone tell me the relationship between the rank and eigenvalues of symmetric positive semidefinite matrix (real domain)? According to simple algebra theorem:
    $$P^{T}AP=diagal(\lambda_{1},\cdot\cdot\cdot,\lambda_{n})$$

I infer to the following conclusion:
$$Rank(A)=number \space of \space nonzero \space eigenvalues$$
Can anyone give me a proof?

Comment: For future readers, that "simple theorem" is called the Spectral Theorem, which gives the decomposition of a psd matrix $A$ as $A = P\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1 ,\ldots, \lambda_n)P^{T}$ where $P$ is a matrix whose columns are eigenvectors of $A$.  We can scale those eigenvectors such that $P$ is orthonormal, whence $P^{T}=P^{-1}$.  Thus, $A=P\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1 ,\ldots, \lambda_n)P^T$ becomes $P^{-1}AP = \mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1 ,\ldots, \lambda_n)$.  Then use $P^{-1}=P^{T}$. 

This may be trivial to some of us, but people reading this post might be beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's there to prove? You're correct.

Let $P$ be the (invertible!) matrix you describe.  We have
$$
\operatorname{rank}(A) = 
\operatorname{rank}(P^TAP) = 
\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n))
$$
the rank of $\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ is the number of $\lambda_i$ such that $\lambda_i \neq 0$.  Your conclusion follows.

Comment: That's right! Thank you so much!